# NSColor Set - What does it do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm following a tutorial, the method bellow belongs in a class sub-classed from `NSview`.  It is just drawing a red rectangle.  I just can't figure out how it is doing it.  I don't understand what the set message is doing in `[bkgColor set]` and how it is effecting the background color?

```
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) rect {
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    NSColor *bkgColor = [NSColor redColor];
    [bkgColor set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect: bounds];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set` method sets the color of the current drawing context for subsequent drawing commands. Think of it as if you have a box of crayons. If you pick up a red crayon, this is equivalent to `[[NSColor redColor] set]`, so now if you draw lines or shapes, they will be in red.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the color in a way that the bezier path fills the rect with red color.
If you don't set the color it used the previous set color (default one if you haven't set one).So if the color was greenColor you would see all the rect filled with green color.Simple as that.